# Feeling that my AngularJS Controller relies on one Promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have made 2 promises in my service. The first one connects to the websocket

```
connect : function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;

    this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost');
    this.socket.addEventListener('open', function (e) { 
        deferred.resolve("connected")
    });
    return promise;
}
```

and the second one sends a message over the websocket

```
send: function (msg, scope) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    this.socket.send(angular.toJson(msg))
    return promise
}
```

In my controller i want to send only when the connection is open. To accomplish that my code looks like this

```
myService.connect()
    .then(function() {
        var myData = myService.send(data);
}

myData.then(function(d) {
    // do something with the data
});
```

It works this way, but why do i have the feeling that this is not the way to be done? I'm pretty new to angularJS and Promises. I feels like creating a new promise inside of a `.then` of another promise is dirty coding.

Found [this](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-promise-chaining-explained) great explanation that does the exact same thing, but still i'm not convinced. If i want to send 20 messages over the websocket, it's like i physically work inside that one `myService.connect` promise the whole controller.

```
myService.connect()
    .then(function() {
        var myData = myService.send(data);
}
    .then(function() {
        var myData = myService.send(data1);
}
    .then(function() {
        var myData = myService.send(data2);
}
    .then(function() {
        var myData = myService.send(data3);
}
```

Comment: remove that var promise = deferred.promise; and do return deferred.promise; at the end

Comment: Having nested promises is a perfectly acceptable way of working. The fact that should a `.then` receive a promise it will actually wait for that promise, or promise chain, to resolve before resolving itself. That should be testimony to the fact.

Comment: @ste2425, So i can rely on the fact that `myService.send(data3)` wil execute only when the websocket  `connect()` is succesfully opened, and `myService.send(data), myService.send(data1) & myService.send(data2)` is succesfully requested and has respond? or that `myService.send(data3)` will be executed even if `myService.send(data)` failed, but will not be executed if `connect()` fails

Comment: I didn't fully understand your comment, but you can rely on the fact that a `.then` will only be called when its corresponding promise is resolved. If a `.then` receives a non promise object it will resolve instantly with that value. If it receives a promise it will resolve once that promise has resolved with the value it resolved with. All of that can be relied on as its the promise spec. Just FYI you want to return the deferred promise not the full deferred object. So `return deferred.promise;` In ES6 promises deferred is considered an anti pattern and isn't available anyway.

Comment: Ran out of characters. `it's like i physically work inside that one myService.connect promise` Don't think of the promise chain as one whole promise. Think of it as separate promises for each `.then` where the current `.then` will only be called once that promise from the last has resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the info and +1 for the side note.

Comment: Sorry for spamming the comments, promise this is the last. However i noticed in your `send`  method you return a promise but never resolve or reject it. Any chained promises after that would hang waiting for your `send` method to resolve. There's no real need for this to return a promise. You can always use `$.resolve()` to create a promise from a non promise object should you want to chain from it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips. appriciate that!